# Why does this coq program not run?

Tags: coq

I'm a beginner of Coq and learning how to make codes with video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJm5TH0GdSo&list=PLt7hcIEdZLAnCoZePG60qgVP4ddP0s3WZ&index=2 .

I made a program following that video (one that starts from almost 29 minutes in video) but it doesn't run as I expected. Could you please tell me why does that happen? I always get stuck in Case.

Program I made is given below:

```
Theorem shugouonajidesho : 
  forall P Q : Prop,
    P/\Q->Q/\P.
Proof. 
  intros P Q H. split.
  Case "Q".
  inversion H as [HP HQ]. imply HQ.
  Case "P".  inversion H as {HP HQ]. imply HP. 
Qed.
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't run as expected? Perhaps it's due to `inversion H as {HP HQ]` where you have `{` instead of `[`?

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your proof, but they're mostly syntactic.

The `Case "Q"` and `Case "P"` syntax comes from Software Foundations. You'd need to import [some particular library](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/sf-3.2/SfLib.html) to be able to use it. If you don't want to do that, it's not necessary. To focus goals, you can use bullets (typically `-`, `+` or `*`). There are other ways too, but this is the most typical.

The `imply` tactic doesn't exist (at least in the standard library). The way you're using it, though, makes me think that you meant `apply`.

In `inversion H as {HP HQ].`, both brackets should be square brackets.

---

Making those changes allows the theorem to work, but I'd also suggest a few changes for idiomaticity.

Using `inversion` is probably overkill here. All you're doing is destructing a conjunction into its parts, so `destruct H as [HP HQ].` would work just as well.

I would also highly recommend separating your proof with line breaks, rather than just putting everything on one line (this might have just been an artifact of how you formatted your question. If so, ignore this). It's fine to put some tactics on the same line, but it should be grouped into logical sections.

Finally, a minor one: I'd suggest putting spaces around `->`. It just makes things a little easier to read.

```
Theorem shugouonajidesho: forall P Q : Prop, P/\Q -> Q/\P.
Proof.
  intros P Q H.
  split.
  - inversion H as [HP HQ].
    apply HQ.
  - inversion H as [HP HQ].
    apply HP.
Qed.
```